# What does the statement if (counter & (1<<j)) mean and how does it work?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was working on an algorithm of sub sequences.

What is the meaning of the statement:

```
if (counter & (1<<j))
```

within the context of the program below:

```
void printSubsequences(int arr[], int n)
{
    unsigned int opsize = pow(2, n);

    for (int counter = 1; counter < opsize; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (counter & (1<<j))
                cout << arr[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<<` means that the left-hand operand is multiplied by 2, for as many times as the number in the right-hand operand. E.g. `1 << 3` means `1*2*2*2`.

Comment: The `counter & (stuff)` results in a *bitwise* `AND` of `counter` and `stuff`

Comment: [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/995714)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The statement:

```
if (counter & (1<<j))
```

checks if the `j`-th bit of `counter` is set. In more detail, `1 << j` uses shifting of `1` to generate a bit mask in which only the `j`-th bit is set. The `&` operator then masks out the `j`-bit of `counter`; if the result is not zero (which means that the `j`-th bit of `counter` was set), the condition is satisfied.

Consider the following example. If `counter` is 320, its binary representation is `101000000`, which means that the 6th bit (the one corresponding to the value of 64) is set; let's test for that bit. The bit mask is generated by shifting `1`, which has the binary representation `000000001`, 6 places to the right, which results in the binary value `001000000`. The value of `counter`, namely:

```
101000000
```

is combined with `&`, which is the bitwise and-operator, with the bit mask as follows:

```
  101000000
& 001000000
  ---------
  001000000
```

The value `001000000` again corresponds to the value of 64; however this is not important here, it only matters that it is not zero (as it has a nonzero bit, namely the bit for which we intended to check). In total, the condition

```
if ( 64 )
```

is satisfied. In the semantics of C (which does not feature a native Boolean data type) any nonzero value is treated as true when checked with `if`.

Comment: can you please give me step by step execution of it?

Comment: The first loop generates all possible combinations and the second loop print according to those combinations. @SarathiShah

Comment: The operation x<<y basically means ' Perform Left shift on binary(x) by y number of bits ' So 6<<2 will give out 24 SINCE --------> lshift(110) by 2 bits -----> 11000  = 24 in decimal.

Comment: Cold door? Cow door? Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

---First for loop run i=0 to i<8 .(explanation - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/)

---Second loop run i=0 to i<3 (for {a,b,c})

1.let's take for first loop i=0 :

```
    j=0,1,2 in this case (0 & (1<<0)),(0 & (1<<1)),(0 & (1<<2)) 
    
    But 0 with & is always 0 so all instance are false for first loop.
```

2. let's take for second loop i=1 :

   j=0 int this case (1 & (1<<0)) it is true so j=0 and arr[0]=a print.

   j=1,2 are false because ( 1 & (1<<1)) & (1 & (1<<2)) are false.
3. let's take for second loop i=2 :

   j=1, int this case (2 & (1<<1)) it is true so j=1 and arr[1]=b print.

   j=0,2 are false because ( 2 & (1<<0)) & (2 & (1<<2)) are false.
4. let's take for second loop i=3 :

   j=0,2 int this case (3 & (1<<2)) & (3 & (1<<2)) it is true so j=0,2 and arr[2] =a & c print.

   j=1 are false because ( 3 & (1<<1))  are false.
5. let's take for second loop i=4 :

   j=2 int this case (4 & (1<<2)) it is true so j=2 and arr[2] =c print.

   j=0,1 are false because ( 4 & (1<<0)) & (4 & (1<<1)) are false.

So this goes on.....